# Card and ListView on single screen

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdown box and a listview below it on a screen.

On selection of a item in dropdownbox, the list view gets populated with multiple cards. As such the logic is working, but somehow having issues with the scroll configuration.

I have the main parent widget like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[locationDropdown(), showPackages(plansLoading)],
    );
}
```

The `locationDropDown()` function returns a card widget with dropdown in it.

`showPackages(plansLoading)` returns a `ListView` widget whose code is like

```
return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
       return Card(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        ///...
         ],
      ),
    ); 
 )
```

Requirement is to keep the card in the `loationDropdown()` widget fixed at its place and the cards generated in `showPackages`'s listview be scrolled.

This is the output I am getting, I am unable to scroll.

[image]

This functionality is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the issue or error logs if any?

Comment: updated the question with the image

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can used SafeArea Widget or use Expanded widget before Listview.
ex.

```
 Column (
  children: <Widget>[
    new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Search something"
    ),
    Expanded(
      ListView(),
    ),
  ]
)
```